# e.target is working only on links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am a noob, I was developing a chrome plugin , which gives the info about the elements clicked on in the web page,

It works fine , but the problem is the e.target works only on links and input boxes, but when I click on some text it does not do anything , it is blank[Expected: the `id/class/etc` of the div within which the text is present]

Here is my code (please do not mark me down, as am really new to this):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var dom_id    = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    var dom_name  = e.target.name.toString();
    var dom_class = e.target.className.toString();
    var dom_html  = e.target.innerHTML;
    var dom_href  = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    var dom_text  = e.target.text;
    var dom_el    = e.target.tagName;
    var dom_src   = e.target.src;
}, false);
```

All I want is when I click on a `div`, I should get the div info, span should give span info, likewise etc.

Comment: I have tried current target but it is not working , it is stopping the script itslef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

Since (based on **[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465530/stopping-content-script-in-chrome-extension)** of yours) it seems the listener is registered properly (e.g. after the DOM has been loaded, the only problem I see, is that you are calling `e.target.name.toString();`.

#### The explanation

It will only work with elements that have the `name` attribute set (not only for links or inputs, but any element that has a `name` attribute). For elements with no `name`, an exception will be raised, as you are calling method `toString` of `undefined` (`e.target.name` equals `undefined` when the `name` attribute is missing).
<sub>(Note that this is not the case with `className`, because `className` refers to the elements property (not directly the `class` attibute and it defaults to an empty string when the `class` attribute is missing.)</sub>

#### The solution

Just remove the `.toString()` part and it will work:

```
var dom_name = e.target.name;
```

<sub>Based on how you use that var later on, you might want to add a check and set it to an empty string if it not defined:

`var dom_name = (e.target.name !== undefined) ? e.target.name : '';`</sub>

Comment: Not really: 1. It implies that the problem is only bound to 'id' (which is not true). 2. It states that `getAttribute()` will throw an error if the attribute is not set (which is not true). 3. The provided code fails to successfully check for an attribute's existence (using `getAttribute()` instead of `hasAttribute()`). 4. It does not describe the real problem (which is calling `toString()` on an undefined object). (Notice that, based on how the code is handled afterwards, the ternary operator might not be at all necessary.)

Comment: Awesome , It worked . I just had to remove the the toString(). thats so cool . thanks so much mate.

Comment: In order to be able to detect such trivial problems yourself in the future, you need to make console log your friend :)

Comment: I will surely do that now , thank you so much mate:)